# Паттерн MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf

Как можно построить архитектуру игры пятнашки с использованием паттерна MVVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо стоит разработать CustomControl, который будет отображать поле игры, и будет формировать соответствующие Команды в ответ на действия пользователя.

Comment: Можно ли более подробно . Какие классы нужно написать в "Model","ViewModel"(особенно не понятно про этот раздел).

Очень нужно разобраться ...

Comment: Вот здесь хорошая статья: http://megadarja.blogspot.com/2010/04/mvvm-wpf.html
Но, в качестве View, вам нужно будет создать специальный кастомный контрол. Стандартные контролы не поддерживают необходимые вам функции.
Еще можно посмотреть документацию на библиотеку Prism от Microsoft. Или другие библиотеки реализующие MVVM pattern.